# Change an img tag according to Google Calendar schedule

Tags: php, javascript, image, api, google-calendar-api

I have a website, where we have a player (click the below link to access it)
[FillyRadio Player](http://fillyradio.com/frvisuals/)

There is an image that sits between the background and in front of the waveform canvas.

I need this image to change to different pictures of various presenters, according to a Google Calendar schedule (makes things easier than farting around with code every time we change a schedule).

Is there any way we can make this img src tag change according to a Google Calendar?

Note: I am very very new to working with an API, so a dumbed down answer would be appreciated!

I am not fussy about the method, as long as it works with Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Would you consider a custom approach not linked with Google Calendar at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to keep the approach as user-friendly as possible (on the image-updating front) without having to rely on time-consuming implementations (i.e., user-friendly interface) is determining the elements which might easily communicate any change to the algorithm. Undoubtedly, these elements are the image files (their names). I have quickly come up with a naming convention delivering what you want (although it is expected to be highly improved by you):

```
07-23-2013_2.jpg (or .png or any pic extension)
3_1.jpg
```

All the names include a "_" which separates the first element ("value") from the second one ("duration"). The value can be certain date (mm-dd-yyyy) or a counter: a certain date means that this image has to be used this day, no matter what; the counter is the default behaviour: if there is no pic with the given date, the algorithm will consider the next one by attending to this counter. The duration means the number of days which the given pic is expected to be up.

Just to explain my point properly, I have created a code accounting for the aforementioned naming structure. But, please, understand the intention of this answer properly: this is just to show you an alternative solution and thus I expect you to change/improve this code a lot.

```
<?php

$goAhead = true;
$today = strtotime(date('Y') . "-" . date('m') . "-" . date('d')); 
$lastValue = 0;

//Checking the last stored date and value
if(file_exists ("./config.ini"))
{
   $lines = file("./config.ini");
   if(count($lines) >= 2)
   {
       if(strstr($lines[0],'-'))
       {
           $temp = explode ('-' , $lines[0] ); 
           $goAhead = false;
           if(isDateGreaterEqual($temp, $today, false))
           {
                //The pic has to be changed no matter what
                $lastValue = (int)$lines[1]; 
                $goAhead = true;
           }
       }
   }
}


$bestVal = $lastValue;
$bestDuration = 0;
$dirName = './images';
$selectedPic = "";
$bestPic = "";
foreach(glob($dirName . '/*.*') as $file) 
{
    if(strstr($file,'_') && strstr($file,'.'))
    {
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $fileNoExtension = basename($file, "." . $ext);

        $temp = explode ('_' , $fileNoExtension ); 

        $startVal = $temp[0]; //Date or number
        $duration = $temp[1]; //Number of days the given pic will be up

        if(strstr($startVal,'-'))
        {
            $temp = explode ('-' , $startVal ); 
            if(isDateGreaterEqual($temp, $today, true))
            {
               //If the pic has today's date, the change has to be performed no matter what
               updateConfig($duration, $lastValue);
               $selectedPic = $file;
               break;
            }
        }
        else if($goAhead)
        {
           //Only in cases where the pic has to be updated
           if((int)startVal < $bestVal)
           {
               $bestVal = (int)startVal;
               $bestDuration = $duration;
               $bestPic = $file;
           }
        }
    }
}

if($bestPic != "")
{
    $selectedPic = $bestPic;
    updateConfig($bestDuration, $bestVal);
}

if($selectedPic != "")
{
    //$selectedPic -> path of the new image
}

 function isDateGreaterEqual($temp, $today, $justEqual) 
 { 
    $conditionMet = false;
    if(count($temp) == 3)
    {
         if(checkdate((int)$temp[0], (int)$temp[1], (int)$temp[2]))
        {
            $stored_date = strtotime($temp[2] . "-" . $temp[0] . "-" . $temp[1]);
            if((!$justEqual && $today >= $stored_date) || ($justEqual && $today == $stored_date))
            {
                //The pic has to be changed no matter what
                $conditionMet = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $conditionMet;
} 

function updateConfig($duration, $curVal)
{
    $finalDate = date('m-d-Y', strtotime("+" . $duration . " days"));
    $file = fopen('./config.ini', 'w') or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($file, $finalDate . "\r\n");
    fwrite($file, $curVal);
    fclose($file);
}

?>
```

This code expects the pictures (with names as described above) to be stored in the folder `images`. It stores the current configuration (date until which the given picture will be shown and the given counter) in a file called `config.ini`. The output from this code is `$selectedPic` which might be blank (no pic change) or include the name of the file of the new picture. This code is expected to be called on a regular basis (just once per day is enough).

The whole point of this proposal is avoiding (usually problematic and unstable) complex calls to external APIs to perform actions which can easily be accomplished internally; that is, a mere proof of concept.

Comment: Interesting. I am assuming this uses the client-side time, and therefore, wouldn't be useful to put this down to the hour (the image is expected to change for 1 and 2 hour periods, as this image is meant to reflect the current DJ on air). I'm pretty sure it would be easy to setup a timezone offset, as well as make the script check by the hour instead of day.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: @WestJ No problem. Regarding your concern, note that this code is 100% PHP and thus should have a 100% server-side behaviour. As said, the whole point of this answer is showing you an alternative way to face the problem and thus you shouldn't just take this code as it is; in any case, I don't see any problem to modify it such that it works per hour. I will not perform this modification; but bear in mind that if your proposal would have been clearer I would have made it to work per hour since the first moment: the clearer the question the more accurate the solution :)